# JSON passing data to php for retrieve

Tags: php, jquery, json

```
(
[addF] => stdClass Object
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [productID] => 33
                [fQty] => 11
                [fPW] => 11
                [fP] => 
                [fH] => PVC
                [fB] => SideBelt
                [fP] => Single Pleat
                [fPanelT] => stdClass Object
                    (
                    )

            )

    )

[addWP] => stdClass Object
    (
    )

[addRBC] => stdClass Object
    (
    )

[addRB] => stdClass Object
    (
    )

[addT] => stdClass Object
    (
    )

)
{"ErrorMessage":true}
```

The above output is base on the follow code below.
    $arrOutput["ErrorMessage"]=print_r($objData);
I have use json to pass the array to PHP but i can't get the data.

i try to set the data but i have no value.

```
$ProductID=isset($objData->allData->addF[0]->productID) ? $objData->allData->addF[0]->productID : "123";
```

i tried to print_r will return true print will output 1

```
$objData->allData
```

it output 1

```
$objData->addF
```

also output 1

i don't understand y i can't set the value after i have decode it.

```
$objData=json_decode(stripslashes($Data));
```

Jquery part

```
allData.addF=addF;
    allData.addWP=addWP;
    allData.addRBC=addRBC;
    allData.addRB=addRB;
    allData.addT=addT;
    //convert the data to json
    var dataString = $.toJSON(allData);
    $.post('test.php',"Data="+escape(dataString),function(data)
    {
        var obj=$.parseJSON(data);
        alert(obj.ErrorMessage);
    });
```

I need help to retrieve the data from it.

Comment: I don't understand why need to call escape() in JavaScript and then stripslashes() in PHP. And it seems like you're also fetching a mysql result directly. You can loop through the mysql result and then copy it to an array so that you won't get the std class object. Then call json_decode() on that array to convert it to json string. Then just call parseJSON on JavaScript to convert the data back into an object.

Comment: there is no SQL at all. basically there is html page there has a list of dynamic field i am trying to use object encode it and pass it to php to decode it and get all the field value out. now i can't get any of the field value printed in the print_r of objData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ProductID=isset($objData->allData->addF->{"0"}->productID)

Comment: object can only be reference using {}.